# In a clash of clans war base what is the best position for gold/elixer mines?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've tried multiple different positions in and outside of my walls. Each position and setup was defended differently with different units.

Comment: Generally, you'll want your "useless" buildings on the outside and defences in the inside, while those with higher hitpoints in areas where your defences are likely to do the most damage... And it all depends on the amount of buildings you have (Town Hall Level).

Comment: Thank you aytimothy I will try and include the units hit points into their location placement

Answer (score 2):

Because you do not lose resources from being attacked in a war, there is no reason to defend the collector and storages. The storages have a lot of health and a bigger radius than the collectors, so putting storages outside of your walls in weak spots of your defences would be ideal. Also, putting the non-defense buildings, except for things like the town hall that actually matters, in places so that the attacker cannot easily lure out the clan castle troops would be an effective strategy. Another choice is to use these buildings to increase the distance between the "red line" and your walls to allow your defences to get extra hits in and kill wall breakers easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't lose any resources, mines are a kind of useless except that they can take some damage and hold up enemy troops in clan wars. Almost everyone normally place the mines outside their base for that reason.

The storages have high health points, use them to hold up enemy troops on strategic places in your base.

Comment: they are not useless.... they "eat" damage and slow down the attack

Comment: Yes they do like any other building, but compare to other higher priority buildings for wars and after looking to the amount of space inside the walls i would say they are relatively useless.

Comment: there's a huge difference for me between totally useless and "not as good as....". try to improve your wording

Comment: look buddy. I didn't want to offend you. But try to improve your answer. It is spreading false information. Answer like like might get downvoted and you will lose hard earned reputation. (notice that I didn't downvote)

Comment: I edited my answer, think its more accurate now. Thanks.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW: What would be an example of a "totally useless building"? I thought it was clear enough that "useless" was essentially saying "does not actively defend your base."

Comment: nothing is totally useless.... everything eats damage and reduces the droparea